# Arrow function, multiple statements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<Button
text='Yes'
onPress={() => { setPopup(false); deleteRow(parameters); console.log('Hello World') }}>
}}/>
```

So I have this arrow function in a button however, it only runs deleteRow(), not setPopup or the console.log and I have no idea why. It means that the popup doesn't disappear when you press 'yes'.

Comment: Add complete component code. Its hard to tell from this

Comment: We need to see `setPopup` code as well.

Comment: ```const [Popup, setPopup] = React.useState(false)```